# How can I append a new TableSection after the 1st TableSection of a TableView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this code to add to the Root of a tableView.

```
tableView.Root.Add(CreateTableSection());
```

But I would like to append after the first section.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Insert`, where `ndx` is an `int` specifying where to insert

```
tableView.Root.Insert(ndx,CreateTableSection());
```

Comment: So to append if there's already only one tableSection I would replace nix with 1 ?

Comment: yes, or just Add() another section.  Add() will always add to the end of the list